# Run two while loops without tkinter or thread modules

Tags: python

How do I make two while loops run at the same time? Here is my code design.

```
while True:
    print(recieve_message()) #this waits for the message
    send_message(input()) #this also waits for the input
```

This will not work, because both codes do not run without waiting. So, I wanted them to run on separate loops, like this:

```
while True:
    print(recieve_message())
while True:
    send_message(input())
```

how do I make these codes run simultaneously?

```
recieve_message
```

and

```
send_message
```

uses the socket module.

Comment: you need to elaborate on question more.There is only one while loop in your pseudocode.

Comment: I meant originally that both codes will not run simultaneously, so it should be run on separate loops, but thanks!

Comment: One way to do this is through the [`signal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html) module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use multithreading:

```
import threading


def f1():
    while True:
        print(recieve_message()) #this waits for the message


def f2():
    while True:
        send_message(input()) #this also waits for the input

threading.Thread(target=f1).start()
threading.Thread(target=f2).start()
```

Comment: process from multiprocessing does a similar thing too. The differences - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044580/multiprocessing-vs-threading-python

Comment: This doesn't really work, since the computer waits for the input, then prints the output. Try it. EDIT: I found out it works in the cmd. Thanks!

Comment: @HyunsooKim Since this works, would you mind accepting it?